# How can I have a persistent data through different Context in a webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

So we have a webservice that is called from different applications and it runs an extraction of data which takes a while and we don't want it to run multiple times. So we thought we could set an HttpContext.Current.Application["isRunning"] to be persistent through all the requests like :

```
 if ((bool)HttpContext.Current.Application["isRunning"])
```

And it doesn't work, since a new HttpContext is created when an other application call the webmethod.

Except writing onto the disk or in AppSettings I don't see how I can persist data through every request to only have one instance of my webmethod running at a time. I've tried with Application, Cache and static variables but they all do not persist across requests. It seems it creates a new instance each time.

Preventing a new instance to be created or persist data through instances would fix the issue. Any hint?

Comment: You can always write a database entry which would be global to your app.  Update accordingly.

Comment: .... I'm at a loss how you're not seeing the value inside of Application being persisted. The application store is a per app domain storage, there seems to be something extremely strange happening such that each request is creating a new app domain? I would recommend putting some logging into the Application_Start event in your global.asax to see if you see that being called repeatedly.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is how he's using the value returned from the ApplicationStore i.e. "isRunning"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following links, which provide useful information on wanting to use the Singleton pattern with web services.

http://forums.asp.net/t/881617.aspx/1

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/72274741-dbbe-4a64-a360-6bbe60026ec9/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use EnterpriseLibraries Caching Block to cache the data following extraction.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/CachingApplicationBlock.aspx

Once you have the Enterprise Library assemblies referenced, it's just a case of adding a few lines to your web.config and then using code such as the following inside your service.

```
 //Create Instance of CacheManager 
 ICacheManager _objCacheManager = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();

 AbsoluteTime timeToExpire = new AbsoluteTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));

        MyData myData = null;
        myData = (MyData)cacheManager.GetData("ref");

        if (myData == null)
        {
            //get the data

            cacheManager.Add("ref", myData, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, timeToExpire);
        }

        return myData;
```